# Find the sum of a column in html table using Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table created using jQuery:

```js
success: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var rows ="";

    function formatItem(data) {
        return '<td>'+data.name + '</td> <td> ' + data.price + ' </td><td>' + "<input></input>" +'</td>';
    }

    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#foodnames"));
    });
}
```

This is what the interface looks like:

[image: this is what interface looks like]

The table is working fine with all the data showing.
The problem is finding the sum of the third column. Where I can enter a number and display it using an id.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: `<input>` is not a container element, there's no `</input>`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use jQuery to select the table, and all of the third td's for each row, then sum it. The basic pseudocode is:

```
Clear the output box.
ForEach TR
   Select the third TD
   Add that value to the output box.
End ForEach
```

To do that in jQuery, you just need to know how to **select the right values.** Assigning relevant class/id names is helpful.

I put together a basic example that you can run. It will tabulate the total of the third column dynamically, as you change the value. I hard coded the price column, but you could easily put some other values or input there.

I put it in an onChange event handler, but if you are loading the data from a server or something, you could do document onLoad or whenever your ajax is complete.

```js
//trigger an event when the input receives a change
$("#exampleTableContainer table td input").off("change").on("change", function(ele) {
  //clear the out put box
  $("#totalOut").val("0");
  //for the table container, select all tr's within the table's tbody. 
  //Excluding tbody will also select the thead.
  $("#exampleTableContainer table tbody tr").each(function(index, rowElement) {
    //tablulate the cost of the current row
    var rowCost = parseInt($(rowElement).find(".cost").text()) * parseInt($(rowElement).find(".amount input").val());
    //if the rowCost is a valid number, add it to whatever is in the output box
    if (rowCost) $("#totalOut").val(parseInt($("#totalOut").val()) + rowCost)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exampleTableContainer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="item">Item</th>
        <th class="cost">Cost</th>
        <th class="amount">Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="item">Item 1</td>
        <td class="cost">123</td>
        <td class="amount">
          <input type="number">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="item">Item 2</td>
        <td class="cost">1</td>
        <td class="amount">
          <input type="number">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="item">Item 3</td>
        <td class="cost">2</td>
        <td class="amount">
          <input type="number">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="item">Item 4</td>
        <td class="cost">4</td>
        <td class="amount">
          <input type="number">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <div>
    Total:
    <input id="totalOut" readonly value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you plan to use this in a production environment or not, so maybe this is overkill for what you're trying to accomplish, but I would recommend using an underlying data model bound to the table.  Then you can get your sum from your data:

```
const data = [
    {food: "Veggie burger", price: 200, qty:1},
    // ...Add as many food items as you like
]
```

You would be able to use the data to build your table:

```
// Get a reference to the table and create a document fragment
const table = document.getElementById("table-body");
const body = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Fill the fragment with your data:
data.map((value, key) => {
  // Row-building logic goes here
  // this probably isn't what you actually do here:
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.className = key;

  for (let x in value) {
    const dataCell = document.createElement("td");
    dataCell.className = x;
    dataCell.innerHTML = value[x];
    row.appendChild(dataCell);
  }

  body.appendChild(row);
});

table.innerHTML = "";
table.appendChild(body);
```

Then you can calculate your sum based on the data, not the UI:

```
const subTotal = data
  .map((value) => value.price * value.qty)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

document.getElementById("total").textContent = subTotal;
```

You would set an event listener on the table(parent node) and use event.target to find the row and column (.qty in this case) and update the corresponding field (qty) in the data object when the input is changed.

```
$("#my-table").on("input", (e) => {
  // You would probably be better off using a custom attribute than a class since there can be multiple classes, but we'll use class to keep it simple:
  const column = $(e.target).parent("td").attr("class");
  const row = $(e.target).parent("td").parent('tr').attr("class");

  data[row][column] = e.target.value;
  console.log(data);
});
```

This pattern also makes it easy to send the updated data back to the REST API to update your database later.

https://jsfiddle.net/79et1gkc/

I know you said you're using jQuery, but ES6 is much nicer in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $("#submit").click(function(){

       $(".user_input").each(function(){
          var value = parseInt($(this).val());
          total += value;

       });
       $("#output").text(total);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="value1" class="user_input"/>
<input type="text" name="value2" class="user_input"/>
<input type="text" name="value3" class="user_input"/>
<button name="submit" id="submit" value="calculate">
Calculate
</button>
<div>
<span>Total:</span><div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `parseInt()`, otherwise this will do concatenation, not addition.

Comment: And it need to be in an event handler, this will do it when the page is loaded, not after the user fills in the inputs.

Comment: thanks. but it seems that the numbers are appending. not adding.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. i did some more tweaking and it worked out.

Comment: Awesome! Goodluck

Comment: had make sure the input fields are not empty and not null

Comment: Yeah I didn't include that I just wanted to give you a basic idea to go off of